# Is Y an exponential Random Variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I had a question about the meaning of exponential random variable. The definition is if X is a random variable that is exponentially distributed, then it has a p.d.f of the form $$\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$

I was wondering, what if I had a random variable with uniform distribution Y, and I defined a new random variable equal to $$Z=e^Y$$ Would Z be exponentially distributed? If yes, would it be an exponentially distributed variable even if Y wasn't uniformly distributed?

Comment: If $Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ then $Z=-\log(Y)$ has an exponential distribution with $\lambda=1$. I have answered this before somewhere on this site but cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ has c.d.f. $F_Y(y)$ and p.d.f. $f_Y(y)=\frac{\operatorname d F_Y(y)}{\operatorname dy}$, and $Z=\operatorname e^Y$, then, for $z\ge 0$,
$$
F_Z(z)=\Bbb P(Z\le z)=\Bbb P(\mathrm e^Y\le z)=\Bbb P(Y\le \log z)=F_Y(\log z)
$$
and
$$
f_Z(z)=\frac{\operatorname d F_Z(z)}{\operatorname dz}=\frac1zf_Y(\log z)
$$
For example,  if $Y$ has a normal distribution, then $Z = \operatorname e^Y$, has a log-normal distribution.

If $Y\sim U(0,1)$, i.e. uniform distribution on the unit interval $(0, 1)$, then  $Z=F^{-1}(Y)$ has an exponential distribution, where $F^{−1}$ is the quantile function, defined by $F^{-1}(p)={\frac {-\ln(1-p)}{\lambda }}$. Moreover, if $Y\sim U(0,1)$, then $1-Y\sim U(0,1)$. This means one can generate exponential r.v. as follows:
$$Z={\frac {-\ln(Y)}{\lambda }}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $[a,b]$  with $a<b$, then the range of $Z=e^Y$
is $[e^a,e^b]$. But the exponential distribution is over all positive reals, so you'd need $a=−\infty,b=\infty$ which doesn't constitute a valid uniform distribution. (This isn't the only problem---the density you get doesn't match either---but this is a sufficient objection to nix this approach.)